# Are all of the backup files & folders of encrypted /home folder also encrypted on the backup HDD?

Tags: ecryptfs

In the past I routinely backed up my entire unencrypted /home folder with LuckyBackup (gui for Rsync) to an external HDD. I've had no problems seeing and manipulating the backed up data when accessing the external backup HDD from a LiveCD, another Ubuntu computer or even Win7.

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS on a new SSD and decided to enable /home folder encryption during installation. Now, when I do a backup of /home to my external HDD using LuckyBackup, I can only see the backed up data on the HDD when I am in logged in to Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to look at or manipulate the data from a LiveCD, another Ubuntu computer or Win7 the data is not accessible and has a user 1000 permission set which can not be changed.

I conclude from this, that all of my backed up data is now saved on my external HDD in encrypted form. I did not expect this, nor do I want it. I want the backed up data saved in unencrypted format so I can access it from other OS's.

Question: Is there a way to backup an encrypted /home partition's data in an unencrypted format, read/copy/executable by any other OS?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to backup the cleartext versions of these files, you'll need to do two things:

- You'll need to be logged in and your home directory will need to be mounted when your backup job runs.
- You'll need to backup your actual home directory, such as `/home/$USER`, rather than just `/home`.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Ubuntu's Encrypted Home Directory feature*

Comment: I didn't enabled the encryption of my home during installation, can I enabled it now or is it recommended to re-install Ubuntu and enable encryption during the install?

Comment: This is a very reasonable question, but it should be asked as a new question of its own, and not a comment here.  Thanks!

Comment: Dustin if I backup my `/home/$USER`  when I'm logged in can I restore that `/home/$USER` by copying to another ubuntu installation home directory?